# Why would one add 1 or 2 to the second argument of snprintf?

Tags: c, qt

What is the role of `1` and `2` in these snprintf functions? Could anyone please explain it

```
snprintf(argv[arg++], strlen(pbase) + 2 + strlen("ivlpp"), "%s%ccivlpp", pbase, sep);
snprintf(argv[arg++], strlen(defines_path) + 1, "-F\"%s\"", defines_path);
```

Comment: No Description about what you are trying? and which technology you are working On?

Answer (score 3):

The role of the `+2` is to allow for a terminal null and the embedded character from the `%c` format, <s>so there is exactly the right amount of space for formatting the first string.</s> but (as [6502](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502) points out), the actual string provided is one space shorter than needed because the `strlen("ivlpp")` doesn't match the `civlpp` in the format itself.  This means that the last character (the second 'p') will be truncated in the output.

The role of the `+1` is also to cause `snprintf()` to truncate the formatted data.  The format string  contains 4 literal characters, and you need to allow for the terminal null, so the code should allocate `strlen(defines)+5`.  As it is, the `snprintf()` truncates the data, leaving off 4 characters.

I'm dubious about whether the code really works reliably...the memory allocation is not shown, but will have to be quite complex - or it will have to over-allocate to ensure that there is no danger of buffer overflow.

---

Since a comment from the OP says:

> I don't know the use of `snprintf()`

```
int snprintf(char *restrict s, size_t n, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

The [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) function formats data like `printf()`, but it writes it to a string (the `s` in the name) instead of to a file.  The first `n` in the name indicates that the function is told exactly how long the string is, and `snprintf()` therefore ensures that the output data is null terminated (unless the length is 0).  It reports how long the string should have been; if the reported value is longer than the value provided, you know the data got truncated.

So, overall, `snprintf()` is a relatively safe way of formatting strings, provided you use it correctly.  The examples in the question do not demonstrate 'using it correctly'.

One gotcha: if you work on MS Windows, be aware that the MSVC implementation of [`snprintf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) does not exactly follow the C99 standard (and it looks a bit as though MS no longer provides `snprintf()` at all; only various alternatives such as `_snprintf()`).  I forget the exact deviation, but I think it means that the string is not properly null-terminated in all circumstances when it should be longer than the space provided.

With locally defined arrays, you normally use:

```
nbytes = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "format...", ...);
```

With dynamically allocated memory, you normally use:

```
nbytes = snprintf(dynbuffer, dynbuffsize, "format...", ...);
```

In both cases, you check whether `nbytes` contains a non-negative value less than the size argument; if it does, your data is OK; if the value is equal to or larger, then your data got chopped (and you know how much space you needed to allocate).

The C99 standard says:

> The snprintf function returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
>   value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been
>   completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`.

Answer (score 2):

The programmer whose code you are reading doesn't know how to use `snprintf` properly. The second argument is the *buffer size*, so it should almost always look like this:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "..." ...);
```

The above is for situations where `buf` is an array, not a pointer. In the latter case you have to pass the buffer size along:

```
snprintf(buf, bufsize, "...", ...);
```

Computing the buffer size is unneeded.

By the way, since you tagged the question as qt-related. There is a very nice `QString` class that you should use instead.

Comment: really I dont know the use of snprintf(), so please clear concept

Answer (score 0):

At a first look both seem incorrect.

1. In the first case the correct computation would be `path + sep + name + NUL` so 2 would seem ok, but for the name the strlen call is using `ilvpp` while the formatting code is using instead `cilvpp` that is one char longer.
2. In the second case the number of chars added is 4 (`-L""`) so the number to add should be 5 because of the ending NUL.

Comment: In the first one, it is `%c` followed by `ilvpp` so the length is correct.

Comment: @Jonathan: On my screen I see `"%s%ccivlpp"` so I count **two** `c` characters after the `%` sign.

Comment: Aaaargh...I need new glasses!